# What's the difference between 开放 (kāi fàng) and 开门 (kāi mén) which both mean "open"?

Tags: usage, difference

From dict.cn:

- [开放](http://dict.cn/%E5%BC%80%E6%94%BE) (kāi fàng) = open
- [开门](http://dict.cn/%E5%BC%80%E9%97%A8) (kāi mén) = open (the) door

I use 开门 in phrases such as 还没开门了吗 (háiméi kāiménle ma?), when I want to know if a shop hasn't opened yet, and 你几点开门 (nǐ jīdiǎn kāimén?), which can be used to ask when a shop opens.

I recently encountered 西门开放时间 (xīmén kāifàng shíjiān) on signage, which translates to west gate opening hours, but I don't recall seeing 开放 before this.

**Question**: What's the difference between 开放 and 开门?

Comment: see dictionaries, e.g. bkrs:  **开放**   1) [come into bloom; unfold]∶花蕾张开 花苞开放了
(2) [lift a ban; lift a restriction]∶解除封锁、 禁令、 限制等、 允许进入 公园今天不开放 to bloom
to open to be open (to the public) to open up (to the outside) to be open-minded unrestrained by convention
unconstrained in one’s sexuality    **开门**   1) open a door (lit./fig.)
2) begin a day's business (of a store)
1) 敞开门户。表示欢迎。
2) 犹公开。
3) 指开设讲席。
4) 指开始营业。
5) 指成家立户。more at bkrs, 100 samples for each at jukuu

Comment: 开放 is a compound of juxtapositional type V-V, 开门 is of
governmental type V-O, which also is separable （离合词）e.g.（１）学校已经开了门了，咱们进去吧，这家商店上个月一直没开过门，那家饭店是什么时候开的？（２）＂开＂后带补语：这家商店每天开两次门（３）＂门＂提到＂开＂前：屋里空气不好，把门开开吧（４)重叠＂开＂：开一开门，把屋子里的烟放出去（５）＂门＂前带定语：那家商店怎么只开了一扇门？
also note transposition 放开 with different meaning：松开。
如：「放开心胸」。to let go to release let go; lift the control over:
放开手脚 have one's hands and feet unfettered
将农副产品价格放开 abandon the control over the price of agricultural and sideline products

Comment: 上海迪士尼2016年6月16日正式开放 (or 开业, 开园)，每天早上7:30开门。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

开门 = open the door

开放 = open to public

开放 means if something is open to public and 开门 means if the **DOOR** is open, this is the key difference.

**For example:**

公园开放了吗？Park's open to public yet?

公园开门了吗？Park's open yet?

The first sentence will only be used if the park isn't officially open yet and you won't use it to check park's opening time everyday.

**Example when you can use 开放 and not 开门:**

经济开放。Open economy.

Obviously you can't use 经济开门 which means Economy open the door

Answer (score 3):

> (1a.) **开门** is a **verb phrase** for '**open door**'.

Example: **开门**, 我要出去 (**open the door**, I have to go out)

> (1b.) It can also figuratively mean '**open** (for business)'

Example: 银行上午9时30分**开门** (the bank **open its door** at 9:30 A.M = the bank **open** (for business) at 9:30 A.M)

> (2a.) **开放**, as a **verb phrase** means '**open for access** ('open to the public' is implied )

Example: 西门於上午9时30分**开放** (the west gate **open** (for access) at 9:00 A.M)

> (2b.) **开放** as an **adjective** means 'open/ liberal'

Example: **开放**政策 (**open** policy); **开放**作风 (**liberal** way)

Answer (score 1):

开放means：open-minded
开门means:open the door
it is different , do you want to know more words discrimination?
you can check here, lots of learning videos you can learn :http://www.hanbridgemandarin.com/course/demo/hsk_grammar

Answer (score 0):

complementary to @Tang Ho answer: Don't use 开放 unless you are sure.

开放 always mean "open up" for previously restricted events/venue/behavior. You cannot use 开放 for anything that is not previously restricted.  In addition,  开放 also carry subliminal meaning on freedom.  Nevertheless, there are bunches of people with poor command of language out there that misleading.

e.g.1

- Events ticket is available from mm-dd-yyyy
- Correct: 节目在某年某月某日【开始】售票
- Wrong: 节目在某年某月某日-开放-售票

e.g.2

- The counter is open at 8:00 am
- Correct: 柜台8点钟才开。
- Wrong: 柜台8点钟才开放。